# Keep only groups in a SQL view that have at least one bigger value then a certain condition

Tags: sql, mysql, hana

I have SQL view `data_start` with 3 columns

```
CALMONTH, COSTCENTER, Kontonummer
```

Sample data:

```
CALMONTH COSTCENTER Kontonummer
-------------------------------
202301      A           AA
202302      A           AB
202101      B           BA
202012      B           BB
202204      C           CA
202312      C           CB
...
```

How can I keep only the rows per `COSTCENTER` group, which `CALMONTH` maximum is greater than a specific value.

So for example I only want to keep the `COSTCENTER` where at least one `CALMONTH` is greater than 202201.

The output should be:

```
CALMONTH COSTCENTER Kontonummer
-------------------------------
202301      A           AA
202302      A           AB
202204      C           CA
202312      C           CB
...
```

I tried this SQL statement:

```
SELECT 
    "CALMONTH", "COSTCENTER", "Kontonummer"
GROUP BY
    ("COSTCENTER") %>%
    SERIES_FILTER(max("CALMONTH") > 202201) %>%,
FROM "data_start"
```

But this results in an error:

> Error Extraneous BY, expecting ‘,’, FROM

The SQL is in the SAP HANA CLOUD and called SQLSCRIPT, which has the syntax from mysql.

Comment: ***WHAT*** error ?!? Please - we **CANNOT** see and read your screen, nor can we read your mind - you need to **SHOW US** all the relevant information! And also: what RDBMS are you using? SQL is just the query language - that doesn't help us much .... are you using Oracle? SQL Server? MySQL? PostgreSQL? DB2?  Please add a relevant tag

Comment: Its in the SAP Datasphere running SQLSCRIPT on the SAP Hana Cloud...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using `group by` and `having` :

First identify `COSTCENTER` having `CALMONTH` maximum is greater than 202201 :

```
  select COSTCENTER
  from data_start
  group by COSTCENTER
  having max(CALMONTH) > 202201
```

Then join this dataset with the table to get the expected output :

```
select t.*
from data_start t
inner join (
  select COSTCENTER
  from data_start
  group by COSTCENTER
  having max(CALMONTH) > 202201
) as s on s.COSTCENTER = t.COSTCENTER;
```

Demo on mysql [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/7HbzFMnB)

Answer (score 1):

You can also make use of CTE [Common_table_expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)
to achieve same result.

```
WITH NewCostCenter AS (
  SELECT COSTCENTER
  FROM data_start
  GROUP BY COSTCENTER
  HAVING MAX(CALMONTH) > 202201
)
SELECT t.*
FROM data_start t
INNER JOIN NewCostCenters s ON s.COSTCENTER = t.COSTCENTER;
```